# 2 php vars with json encode in javascript

Tags: php, variables, json

I have a problem with my script. If I have two JSON_ENCODE lines my script doesn't work anymore.

```
var time= <?php echo json_encode($time_cell); ?>;
var time2= <?php echo json_encode($time_cell2); ?>;
```

Why? Is there any other method to get this PHP vars?

Answer (score 0):

JSON encoded string needs to be parsed in Javascript.

You can do somthing like this:

```
var time=JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($time_cell); ?>");
var time2=JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($time_cell2); ?>");
```

You mey read more here on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).